# Bash script help on RPi

Tags: bash, apache-httpd

I have a bash script that runs every hour. Output of this is sent to me via email. This is run through cronjob.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Script: temp_email.sh
# -------------------------------------------------------

cpu=$(</sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp)
echo "$(date) @ $(hostname)"
echo "-------------------------------------------"
echo "GPU => $(/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp)"
echo "CPU => $((cpu/1000))'C"
echo "-------------------------------------------"
echo ""
echo ""
```

As of now it provides temperatures via email. I wanted to add a loop and self-healing to mounted drives and http service.

I am using following commands to get results of apache2 service status

```
systemctl list-units --no-legend apache2.service | cut -d' ' -f4
```

The output if the service is running is "`running`". I want the loop to attempt to start the service if the status is anything but running. Output of this attempt.

I use the following to check status of external drives mounted to the Raspberry Pi.

```
 lsblk -dlno NAME,MOUNTPOINT /dev/sd??*
```

Again, I want to put this in a loop wheirein if the drive is unmounted it will first gracefully stop the apache2 service, mount the drive and later start the apache2 service.

I am unable to get "if & then statements" correctly. I do not want any changes in case both the service and drives are running as they should.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As I don't know how the output from `systemctl` command should be, I just will give you the steps I would follow:

- Don't use a loop. Use `cron` to execute your script periodically.
- Process the output of `systemctl` with `grep` for searching for a pattern of interest indicating mount status, and store this response.
- Process your response using an `if` to execute `lsblk` if needed

It would be something like this:

```
# script.sh
apache_running=1
systemctl status apache2.service | grep "running" || apache_running=0

if [ $apache_running -eq 0 ]
then
  echo "Apache is not running"
  lsblk -dlno NAME,MOUNTPOINT /dev/sd??*
else
  echo "Apache is running"
fi
```

Then, you add your script.sh file as an entry to the `crontab`

Comment: Thank you and just a quick response that I do use cronjob for the script. Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure how will work. I see only one If statement and there should be two (according to me) -- One for apache status and one for the mounted drives both having their actions.

Comment: In that case, you will have to check 2 conditions (with an AND operator), one for apache status and another for device status. If you have a list of devices to check, you can iterate through them in a for, I guess. It would be helpful If you provide an example output for each case.

Comment: I updated the answer for Apache service checking. But, what is the output of `lsblk` and how you identify the device to re-mount?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of parsing the output of `systemctl list-units`, use `systemctl is-active`, and you can do things like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Mount point names in systemd unit style, with initial slash omitted and the
# rest replaced by dashes:
MOUNTPOINTS="MOUNT-POINT1 MOUNT-POINT2"

FAILED=0
for mountpoint in $MOUNTPOINTS
do
    if ! systemctl -q is-active $mountpoint.mount
    then
        echo "$mountpoint.mount is not active."
        if systemctl -q is-active apache2.service
        then
            echo "Stopping Apache first..."
            systemctl stop apache2.service
        fi
        echo "Trying to fix $mountpoint.mount..."
        systemctl start $mountpoint.mount || FAILED=1
    fi
done

if [ $FAILED -ne 0 ]
then
    echo "A mountpoint was down and we failed to fix it. Panic!" >&2
    exit 69 # EX_UNAVAILABLE
fi

if ! systemctl -q is-active apache2.service
then
    echo "apache2 service is not active. Attempting to start."
    systemctl start apache2.service
fi
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Could you please try and help with the output of Apache2 at the end? As in, is there a way to find out if the apache restart worked or not?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to trying to do this yourself in a shell script might be to install and configure Monit to do it for you: https://mmonit.com/monit/